Different color indexes in ggplot2
I'm graphing some light level data and want to overlay the twilights (sunrise and sunset). These need to be on two color scales and after consulting chatGPT and google, I cannot figure out how to do it! I would appreciate any help I can get.
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data, mapping = aes(x = EST_Date, y = shifted_minutes, color = light_log), shape = 15) +
  geom_point(data_twilight, mapping =  aes(x = EST_Date, y = shifted_minutes, fill = twilight)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = y_breaks,
    labels = y_labels,
    limits = c(0, 1440)
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Value",
    y = "Time"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("sunrise" ="orange", "sunset"="blue")) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "black", high = "white")   +
  theme_minimal() +
geom_hline(yintercept = y_breaks, color = "red", linetype = "solid")

This is basically perfect, except for the fact that my sunrise and sunset are black. I've also tried scale_color_manual and scale_color_discrete with no luck.

My data sets are too big to insert using dput so I've only included the first 50 lines. That will result in your graph looking different than mine.
> dput(head(data, n=50))
structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1677647073, 1677647373, 
1677647673, 1677647973, 1677648273, 1677648573, 1677648873, 1677649173, 
1677649473, 1677649773, 1677650073, 1677650373, 1677650673, 1677650973, 
1677651273, 1677651573, 1677651873, 1677652173, 1677652473, 1677652773, 
1677653073, 1677653373, 1677653673, 1677653973, 1677654273, 1677654573, 
1677654873, 1677655173, 1677655473, 1677655773, 1677656073, 1677656373, 
1677656673, 1677656973, 1677657273, 1677657573, 1677657873, 1677658173, 
1677658473, 1677658773, 1677659073, 1677659373, 1677659673, 1677659973, 
1677660273, 1677660573, 1677660873, 1677661173, 1677661473, 1677661773
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), light = c(1.136, 
1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 
1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 
1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 
1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 
1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 
1.136, 1.136, 1.136, 1.136), twilight = c("night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night"), EST_datetime = structure(c(1677647073, 
1677647373, 1677647673, 1677647973, 1677648273, 1677648573, 1677648873, 
1677649173, 1677649473, 1677649773, 1677650073, 1677650373, 1677650673, 
1677650973, 1677651273, 1677651573, 1677651873, 1677652173, 1677652473, 
1677652773, 1677653073, 1677653373, 1677653673, 1677653973, 1677654273, 
1677654573, 1677654873, 1677655173, 1677655473, 1677655773, 1677656073, 
1677656373, 1677656673, 1677656973, 1677657273, 1677657573, 1677657873, 
1677658173, 1677658473, 1677658773, 1677659073, 1677659373, 1677659673, 
1677659973, 1677660273, 1677660573, 1677660873, 1677661173, 1677661473, 
1677661773), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
    EST_time = structure(c(273, 573, 873, 1173, 1473, 1773, 2073, 
    2373, 2673, 2973, 3273, 3573, 3873, 4173, 4473, 4773, 5073, 
    5373, 5673, 5973, 6273, 6573, 6873, 7173, 7473, 7773, 8073, 
    8373, 8673, 8973, 9273, 9573, 9873, 10173, 10473, 10773, 
    11073, 11373, 11673, 11973, 12273, 12573, 12873, 13173, 13473, 
    13773, 14073, 14373, 14673, 14973), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), EST_Date = structure(c(19417, 
    19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 
    19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 
    19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 
    19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 
    19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 19417, 
    19417, 19417, 19417, 19417), class = "Date"), band_number = c("2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150"), 
    light_log = c(0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 
    0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896, 0.12751332029896), Month = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), minutes = c(4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 
    49, 54, 59, 64, 69, 74, 79, 84, 89, 94, 99, 104, 109, 114, 
    119, 124, 129, 134, 139, 144, 149, 154, 159, 164, 169, 174, 
    179, 184, 189, 194, 199, 204, 209, 214, 219, 224, 229, 234, 
    239, 244, 249), shifted_minutes = c(544, 549, 554, 559, 564, 
    569, 574, 579, 584, 589, 594, 599, 604, 609, 614, 619, 624, 
    629, 634, 639, 644, 649, 654, 659, 664, 669, 674, 679, 684, 
    689, 694, 699, 704, 709, 714, 719, 724, 729, 734, 739, 744, 
    749, 754, 759, 764, 769, 774, 779, 784, 789)), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(data_twilight, n=50)
+ )
structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1677670140, 1677712740, 
1677756300, 1677800040, 1677842040, 1677886320, 1677928740, 1677973440, 
1678014900, 1678059540, 1678101000, 1678146180, 1678187100, 1678232640, 
1678273560, 1678319340, 1678359840, 1678406040, 1678446000, 1678491540, 
1678532400, 1678577940, 1678619100, 1678664880, 1678705260, 1678751580, 
1678792200, 1678837980, 1678877700, 1678924980, 1678963800, 1679010840, 
1679050800, 1679096640, 1679137200, 1679183580, 1679223360, 1679270580, 
1679309460, 1679356740, 1679396400, 1679443380, 1679481300, 1679529540, 
1679568600, 1679616840, 1679654400, 1679702640, 1679740800, 1679789040
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), light = c(1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5), twilight = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), levels = c("sunrise", "sunset"), class = "factor"), EST_datetime = structure(c(1677670140, 
1677712740, 1677756300, 1677800040, 1677842040, 1677886320, 1677928740, 
1677973440, 1678014900, 1678059540, 1678101000, 1678146180, 1678187100, 
1678232640, 1678273560, 1678319340, 1678359840, 1678406040, 1678446000, 
1678491540, 1678532400, 1678577940, 1678619100, 1678664880, 1678705260, 
1678751580, 1678792200, 1678837980, 1678877700, 1678924980, 1678963800, 
1679010840, 1679050800, 1679096640, 1679137200, 1679183580, 1679223360, 
1679270580, 1679309460, 1679356740, 1679396400, 1679443380, 1679481300, 
1679529540, 1679568600, 1679616840, 1679654400, 1679702640, 1679740800, 
1679789040), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
    EST_time = structure(c(23340, 65940, 23100, 66840, 22440, 
    66720, 22740, 67440, 22500, 67140, 22200, 67380, 21900, 67440, 
    21960, 67740, 21840, 68040, 21600, 67140, 21600, 67140, 25500, 
    71280, 25260, 71580, 25800, 71580, 24900, 72180, 24600, 71640, 
    25200, 71040, 25200, 71580, 24960, 72180, 24660, 71940, 25200, 
    72180, 23700, 71940, 24600, 72840, 24000, 72240, 24000, 72240
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), EST_Date = structure(c(19417, 
    19417, 19418, 19418, 19419, 19419, 19420, 19420, 19421, 19421, 
    19422, 19422, 19423, 19423, 19424, 19424, 19425, 19425, 19426, 
    19426, 19427, 19427, 19428, 19428, 19429, 19429, 19430, 19430, 
    19431, 19431, 19432, 19432, 19433, 19433, 19434, 19434, 19435, 
    19435, 19436, 19436, 19437, 19437, 19438, 19438, 19439, 19439, 
    19440, 19440, 19441, 19441), class = "Date"), band_number = c("2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", 
    "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150", "2227_58150"), 
    light_log = c(0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164, 
    0.405465108108164, 0.405465108108164), Month = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), minutes = c(389, 1099, 385, 1114, 374, 1112, 
    379, 1124, 375, 1119, 370, 1123, 365, 1124, 366, 1129, 364, 
    1134, 360, 1119, 360, 1119, 425, 1188, 421, 1193, 430, 1193, 
    415, 1203, 410, 1194, 420, 1184, 420, 1193, 416, 1203, 411, 
    1199, 420, 1203, 395, 1199, 410, 1214, 400, 1204, 400, 1204
    ), shifted_minutes = c(929, 199, 925, 214, 914, 212, 919, 
    224, 915, 219, 910, 223, 905, 224, 906, 229, 904, 234, 900, 
    219, 900, 219, 965, 288, 961, 293, 970, 293, 955, 303, 950, 
    294, 960, 284, 960, 293, 956, 303, 951, 299, 960, 303, 935, 
    299, 950, 314, 940, 304, 940, 304)), row.names = c(NA, 50L
), class = "data.frame")

I apologize if you wanted more data, but I'm just not in the spot right now to upload files of this data.
Thank you!

Minimal reproducible examples are great. As long as it's enough to demonstrate the problem, 5 rows is much better than 5000.

You are using fill to control the sunrise/sunset color. The default geom_point shape only has color, no fill. You could use geom_point(shape = 21) to make it show your fill. See ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, fill = cyl)) + geom_point(shape = 21) with and without the shape specification.

@GregorThomas thank you. Normally I get yelled at on here when I don't post many rows...

That's shocking. The only cases where more rows are needed are when (a) the small sample is too small to illustrate the problem, or (b) when efficient performance on large data is the goal, so solutions need to be tested at scale. Feel free to @ tag me by commenting on this question and posting a link if anyone gives you a hard time about a small example.

Did you forget to add
, shape = 21

to the geom_point() that plots data_twilight? Try
geom_point(data_twilight, mapping =  aes(x = EST_Date, y = shifted_minutes, fill = twilight), shape = 21) +
 


that worked!!! I had no idea it would be this simple... thank you
